# Extracting Rows of Data from Excel Table and Inserting into an Existing dataverse table

Tags: power-automate

I have a Power Automate flow that takes in an excel file with a table of data. My objective is to get each row of data from excel, and add it to a row in a dataverse table I have already created.

My flow is as follows:

[image]

When the flow is executed it fails here and I am pretty sure it has to do with how I am trying to retrieve the values from the array of data that is returned from the first loop:

[image]

These are the values returned to me from the list rows present in a table action:

[image]

And this is how I am trying to retrieve them:

[image]

I know how I am trying to get each value is what is causing it to fail, but how would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://www.powertechtips.com/loop-through-array-power-automate/

And: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/While-using-array-variable-got-The-template-language-expression/td-p/452395

The error usually happens when you're trying to access an element at an index that is greater than the length of the array. To debug further you can add a Compose action inside your `Apply to each loop` to output the current item of the array.

Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kupz71dWYyY

Comment: I cannot access the current item inside the apply to each loop for some reason

Comment: Take a look at this and see if you are accessing it the right way: https://www.powertechtips.com/loop-through-array-power-automate/

Comment: Yes that worked for me, thank you

Comment: Nice, I updated my comment with the link, please accept the solution.